# Django custom Admin Action : how to deselect on completion?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have written a Django custom Admin Action (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). This type of thing :

[image]

My Admin Action produces a download file containing information from the selected rows.

Ideally I would like those rows which have been selected to be de-selected once the download has taken place.

Is there an established way of doing this ? Presumably with the help of some JS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a file (=direct download) then it doesn't really matter what happens server-side between the request and the response - you need to do this client-side, clear the checkboxes after submitting the form.

So extend change_list.html and insert some extra Javascript.
Something along the lines of:

```
$('#changelist-form').submit(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#changelist-form input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }, 100);
});
```